# Split file based on multiple occurrence of delimiter

Tags: python, regex

I ran into the following task to split a file based on multiple occurrences of a delimiter.
I have a file which has following data:

```
Number of Employees       - 95

==============================================================================
 Telephone Number -  972123111111
 Empl Name  -   David
 Designation  - Software Engineer
 Address: **********
 Doamin: Python
==============================================================================
 Telephone Number -  972123111112
 Empl Name  - Glen
 Designation  - Software Engineer
 Doamin: Python
==============================================================================
 Telephone Number -  972123111111
 Empl Name  - Jhon
 Designation  - Software Engineer
 Address: **********
 Doamin: Python
==============================================================================
```

In this file I want to split each employee information in between "=" and then print the contents for all employees like below:

```
Details of Employee: (Employee Name)
  Telephone Number: (employee telephone number)
  Designation : (employee desgination)
```

I have written the code to fetch data from a file into a variable and use below regular expression for grepping the data but to no avail:

```
re.findall('[^=]=*.*?[=*$]', a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this snippet, it store all employee data as dictionaries in a whole list

```
import re
data_separator_regepx     = "-|:" #theres - and : as separators in sample text
employee_separator_regexp ="^=+$"
employees      = []
with open('test.txt') as f_in:
    curr_employee = {}
    for idx,line in enumerate(f_in):
        if not idx : continue #skip first line
        line = line.strip()
        if not line: continue #skip empty lines
        if re.match(employee_separator_regexp,line):
            if curr_employee:
                employees.append(curr_employee)
                curr_employee = {}
        else:
            line = re.split(data_separator_regepx,line)
            key, value = line[0],line[1]
            curr_employee[key.strip()]=value.strip()

for employee in employees:
    print "Details of Employee: ({})".format(employee.get('Empl Name',''))
    print "Telephone Number: ({})".format(employee.get('Telephone Number',''))
    print "Designation: ({})".format(employee.get('Designation',''))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have a small doubt in the above code where you are skipping the 1st line using idx. How can I skip 'n' lines using. Because it is a very huge file with lot of data on top

Comment: if idx<first_data_line: continue

Answer (score 2):

Use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) instead of `re.findall()` like so:

```
re.findall(r'^=+$', a)
```